# How to pass an integer value of select list to controller in laravel?

Tags: controller, php-7.2, laravel-5.7

I want to pass value of select list from view to my controller.The value is `course_id`. When I put `dd(request->all())` in my controller, `course_id` is an string.In controller I cast it to integer and I assign to model object but always zero is inserted in `course_id` field of `media` table.
this is my view:

```
<form action="../media" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{csrf_field()}}
title: <input type="text" name="title">
<br> <br>
type:
<input type="radio" name="type" value="voice" checked>Voice<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="video">Video<br>
<br> <br>
link: <input type="file" name="link">
<br><br>
course:
<select name="$courses" >
    @foreach($courses as $course)
        <option value="{{$course->id}}">
            {{$course->title}}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="submit">
```

this is store controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    //dd($request->all());
    $media=new Media();
    $media->title=$request->title;
    $media->type=$request->type;
    $media->course_id=(int)($request->courses);
    $media->save();
    $format=$request->file('link')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $size=$request->file('link')->getSize();
    $name=$request->type.'-'.$media->id.'.'.$format;
    $request->file('link')->move(public_path('medias'),$name);
    $media->link= $name;
    $media->format=$format;
    $media->size=$size;
    $media->save();
    return back();
}
```

And this is create controller:

```
 public function create()
{
    $courses=Course::all();
    return view('Admin.Media.create',compact('courses'));
}
```

Comment: Check your rendered HTML; I'm not sure what `name="$courses"` is going to render as, but at a glance I don't think it would be `course_id`. Also, you say *"in my controller, course_id is an string.In controller I cast it to integer [...]"* but you're actually casting `$request->courses` and not `$request->course_id`; gotta do some more thorough debugging on your end.

Comment: The name of course_id is courses in html view and I mentioned it in select tag. Even I receive all courses of course table in select list in my view. I only can't convert string to integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
select name="$courses"
```

in your HTML, you're gonna get

```
"$courses" => null, // or 1, 2 etc.
```

in your `$request` variable; which is going to be difficult to access. Use

```
select name="courses" <!-- Without the $ -->
```

And access as `$request->courses` in your Controller.

Note: You *shouldn't* have to cast to `int` due to the way PHP handles types, but likely doesn't hurt.